# Proving the equality of sequences' limit

Tags: limits, summation

Prove that if $a_n$ is convergent, then 
$M_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n} a_n$
satisfies $\lim M_n=\lim a_n$.

(sorry for English)

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, it looks like it is Cauchy's First Theorem on limits whose proof is available online.

Comment: If $\lim a_n = a$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ only finitely many terms of the sequence $(a_n)$ differ from $a$ by more than $\varepsilon$. What implication does this have on $\sum_{i = 1}^m a_m$ for some positive integer $m$?

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an index $n$ such that $|M_n-a|<\varepsilon$, where $a=\lim_na_n$. Fix $N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon/2, n>N$. Then for $n>N$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i-a\right|&\leqslant\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-a)\right|\\
& \leqslant\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N(a_i-a)\right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=N+1}^n(a_i-a)\right|=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon
\end{aligned}$$
provided $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Hi, frog, can you explain me why $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i-a \right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-a)\right| $$. I think that is equal. :/
And, what is O(1/n)??

Comment: Sure you are right, it is equal $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-a)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i-\frac{1}{n}n a = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i-a$. But the second inequality is an inequality by the triangle inequality. And $O(1/n)$ is a Landau symbol. It means that the first term in my last line of the inequality is bounded by a constant divided by $n$ and can be made arbitrary small provided $n$ is large enough. This holds since the finite sum is (of course) finite.